# Adding a links to existing D3 Tree

Tags: d3.js

I have created the following tree structure. I want to draw a line/chord between the purple nodes. My data is tree structure, but for visualization purposes I want to add this link. Is there any way of doing so?

[image: Existing tree]

Comment: It might help if you at least provide a sample of the data object you are using.

Comment: @Mattrition thanks.  **UPDATE**:Here is a snipts of the tree. 
 {"children": [{"group": 1, "id": "RID1", "name": "RadLex entity"}, {"group": 2, "id": "RID15849", "name": "Obsolete Radlex Term"}], "group": 2, "id": "RID0", "name": "Radlex ontology entity"}. Let say I want to connect note-RID15849 with node-RID0

Comment: You can get the coordinates of the nodes and add a line that connects them manually.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff THANKS!  Can you please elaborate a bit more on this? I'm using JSON to read the tree & I used this as base code: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

Comment: The data for the nodes you're interested in will give you the x and y positions after running the layout. Then all you have to do is connect them, e.g. with an SVG `line`.